# Attach Debugger - "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: *. Path '', line 0, position 0"

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

When I try to attach a debugger to my Azure server through Cloud Explorer, I receive this error:

> Cloud Explorer has encountered an unexpected error.
>
> The requested action could not be completed.
>
> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: Y. Path '', line 0, position 0

I tried reinstalling everything. I have Azure SDK 2.9.6 installed.

EDIT: I have completely reinstalled Windows, Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3, but I still get the issue.

Comment: Is your VS IDE up to date? I've seen this version before with out of date IDEs.

Comment: @MartynC Everything is up to date.

Comment: At what point does this fail? I see this error is sometimes received when incorrectly parsing a json object. Do you have any breakpoints set up? Could it be that you are actually starting a debug session and an exception is thrown?

Comment: I get this error right when clicking "Attach Debugger" on my Azure server. Using Server Explorer instead of Cloud Explorer works, but I want this fixed.

Comment: @MortenMoulder I am getting the same issue. Will be watching with interest if you manage to solve please post answer.

Comment: I wonder, I've just installed this combo, everything works, but on my other PC I have the same error.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? I have the same tools installed as you and I get the same error.

Comment: @TCM Nope, I have not been able to fix this. I simply use the Server Explorer instead.

Comment: Same problem here - VS2015 Community Edition. Latest Azure SDK.

Answer (score 6):

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, and I have had this problem as well, so, I contacted Microsoft Support, they said this is a known issue, and they are hoping to have a fix for it in the near future. However, as you mentioned in your comments above, as a work around you can use the Server Explorer in Visual Studio, which worked for me. Also. another work around is to attach to it manually from the debug option menu.

Tech support response "This appears to be a problem with Cloud explorer related to RBAC and contributor role."

Which sounds like it has more to do with the Azure side of things than directly with your Visual Studio install.

To verify, I posted a couple emails with tech support responses below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, and I resolved this by unistalling Azure tools 2.9(because this tool has a bug) and reinstall Azure tools 2.8.2 and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Azure SDK for .NET v2.9.6.

When I opened the Microsoft Web Platform Installer I could pick newer version 3.0.1, now I can finally connect to the remote App Service through Visual Studio's Cloud Explorer window.

Answer (score -1):

@MortenMoulder, have you cleared IE data and cache, after this login in Azure Portal? Have you tried to apply remote debugging from Server Explorer? Also, take in consideration to revert to  2.8

Comment: Not an answer. Fresh install of Windows and I still get this issue. Definitely not an issue with cache. Server Explorer works fine.